# Conditional Replace in two data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames with several thousand lines, which are like the following two data frames:

[image]
[image]

I want the value of the goal column in the first data frame to be moved to the second data frame wherever the names of the campaigns are the same in the first and second data frames. I mean something like the following data frame:

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to do left join with df_1 in the left side and then use the existing goal column in df_1 to fill the nulls produced by join.

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame()
df_2 = pd.DataFrame()

df_1['campaign'] = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
df_1['goal'] =['order', 'order', 'off', 'order']

df_2['campaign'] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
df_2['goal'] = ['Subscription', 'order', 'Subscription']

# left join
df = df_1.merge(df_2.rename(columns={'goal': 'new_goal'}), on=['campaign'], how='left')
# replace nulls 
df['new_goal'].fillna(df['goal'], inplace=True)

df

+---+----------+-------+--------------+
|   | campaign | goal  |   new_goal   |
+---+----------+-------+--------------+
| 0 |    a     | order | Subscription |
| 1 |    b     | order |    order     |
| 2 |    c     |  off  | Subscription |
| 3 |    d     | order |    order     |
+---+----------+-------+--------------+
```

You can select the columns you need and rename them as per your need

```
df_final = df[['campaign', 'new_goal']].rename(columns={'new_goal': 'goal'})
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use pandas.DataFrame.merge for that:

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'campaign': ['a','b','c','d'], 'goal': ['order','order','off','order']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'campaign': ['a','b','c'], 'goal': ['subscription','order','subscription']})

df_out=pd.merge(df2,df1,on='campaign',how='left',suffixes=('_df2','_df1'))
```

Result:

```
  campaign      goal_df2 goal_df1
0        a  subscription    order
1        b         order    order
2        c  subscription      off
```

Comment: I tried this method but duplicate rows and columns are created in the data frame

Answer (score -1):

This will overwrite values in df1

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'campaign':['a','b','c','d'],'goal':['order','order','off','order',]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'campaign':['a','b','c','d'],'goal':['Subscription','order','Subscription','order',]})
```

```py
df2.merge(df1, how= 'left')

>>  campaign    goal
    0   a   Subscription
    1   b   order
    2   c   Subscription
    3   d   order
```